# How to filter Flux asynchronously

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I need to check if a substring is contained in title of shop or stocks in this shop.

```
 @Override
    public Flux<Shop> searchShopsBySearchingTextInShopsAndStocks(String searchText) {

// I received Flxux<List<Shop>> 
 return shopRepo.findAll().
   // next I check if substring in title of shop
   filter(shop -> {
         if (shop.getTitle().contains(searchText) || shop.getDescription().contains(searchText)) {
                                            
                       // if contains then return TRUE if not check in stocks
                        return true;
                    } else {
                                 // reeived all stock Flux<List<Stock>> of this shop and check
                          return stockService.findStocksByShopId(shop.getId()).
                                flatMap(stock -> {
                                    if (stock.getDescription().contains(searchText) || stock.getTitle().contains(searchText)) {

           // and in this place I need help

                                        return  // true
                                    }

                                    return //false 
                                });

          });
}
```

When checking the content of a substring in stocks, one occurrence is enough for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at `Flux#filter` operator signature:

```
Flux<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> p)
```

we see that it accepts a simple Java Predicate as a parameter. You can not perform asynchronous operations within it.

You can use `filterWhen` operator instead:

```java
shopRepo.findAll()  
    .filterWhen(shop ->
        (shop condition) ? Mono.just(true) :
                stockService.findStocksByShopId(shop.getId())
                        .map(stock -> (stock condition)))
```