# Project Reactor: Obtain Size of List Contained Within a Mono

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to do something again here in project reactor that I'm sure is reeeeeal simple for any of you project reactor gurus out there!
I've been searching and scratching around with this one for a while now, and feel I'm once again hitting a wall with this stuff.

All I'm trying to do is determine if a List of objects contained within a Mono is empty or not.

This is what I have so far:

```
private Mono<Boolean> isLastCardForAccount(String accountId) {
    return cardService.getAccountCards(accountId)
        .hasElement();
}
```

I'm thinking the above might work, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to extract/access the 'Boolean' contained within the returned Mono. I think I have to use 'subscribe' somehow right?
I've mucked around with this stuff for a while now, but still no luck.

Here is how 'getAccountCards' is defined:

```
public Mono<List<Card>> getAccountCards(final String accountId) {
    return cardCrudRepository.getCardsByAccountId(accountId)
        .collectList();
}
```

From CardCrudRepository:

```
//  @Query("SELECT * FROM card WHERE account_id = :accountId") <-Not sure if I need this
Flux<Card> getCardsByAccountId(String accountId);
```

And lastly, how I'm using 'isLastCardForAccount':

```
public Mono<Void> updateCardStatus(String accountId, String cardId, String cardStatus) {
    return accountService.getAccount(accountId)
        .map(Account::getClientId)
        .map(clientId -> createUpdateCardStatusServiceRequestData(clientId, cardId, cardStatus))
        .flatMap(requestData -> cartaClient.updateCardStatus(requestData)
            .then(Mono.defer(() -> isCardBeingCancelled(cardStatus) ? allCardsCancelledForAccount(accountId) ? removeAccount(accountId) : 
(isLostOrStolen(cardStatus) ? replaceCard(cardId, cardStatus).flatMap(this::updateCardNumber) : Mono.empty()) : Mono.empty())));
}
```

As always, any and all help and insight is tremendously appreciated!

Comment: isCardBeingCancelled(cardStatus) returns Boolean or Mono<Boolean> ??

Comment: Check this code . You will get some idea       

`Flux<Integer> integerFlux = Flux.just(1,2,3,4,5,6);`
        `integerFlux.count().subscribe(System.out::println);`
        `integerFlux.collectList().map(list->list.size()).subscribe(System.out::println);`

Comment: Hi @Harry.

here is the code to answer your question:

private boolean isCardBeingCancelled(String cardStatus) {
 return isCardDamagedFraudulentOrBeingBlocked(cardStatus);
}

So the answer is a "boolean."

Comment: Thankyou @AjitSoman. I will see if I can somehow use that code.

Comment: can you explain in basic english what logic you are trying to achieve in the `then` operator? It's very difficult to follow

Comment: Sure @MichaelMcFadyen...here goes: check if the (pre-paid)card whos status is being updated is being updated to 'cancelled', if so check to see if all the cards associated with this account are also 'cancelled', if they are, then remove the account. Else, check if the card status is either 'lost' or 'stolen', if it is, replace the card, else just do nothing by returning an empty Mono. Does that explain it or no?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would resolve the issue but this way you can try to write your logic

```
 return accountService.getAccount(accountId)
            .map(Account::getClientId)
            .map(clientId -> createUpdateCardStatusServiceRequestData(clientId, cardId, cardStatus))
            .flatMap(requestData -> cartaClient.updateCardStatus(requestData)
                    .then(Mono.defer(() ->
                            Mono.zip( 
                                    Mono.just(isCardBeingCancelled(cardStatus)),
                                    isLastCardForAccount(accountId),
                                    Mono.just( isLostOrStolen(cardStatus) )
                                    ) 
                                    .map(tuple -> {
                                                WRITE YOUR IF ELSE LOGIC 

                                            })
```

The idea is to use zip and then use the tuple for writing logic. The Tuple would be of type Tuple3 of <Boolean, Boolean ,Boolean>. I made the assumption that isLostOrStolen(cardStatus) returns Boolean.

Comment: Thanks @Harry! I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is by using `filterWhen` operator like this:

```java
.then(Mono.defer(() -> {
    if (isCardBeingCancelled(cardStatus)) {
        return Mono.just(accountId)
            .filterWhen(this::allCardsCancelledForAccount)
            .flatMap(this::removeAccount);
    } else if (isLostOrStolen(cardStatus)) {
        return replaceCard(cardId, cardStatus).flatMap(this::updateCardNumber);
    }
    return Mono.empty();
}))
```

You can use `filterWhen` in the case of asynchronous filtering. Check [this](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which.filtering) section of [Which operator do I need?](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which-operator) reference and this [How to filter Flux asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70168625/how-to-filter-flux-asynchronously).

As a side note, this is not going to work as you expect:

```java
private Mono<Boolean> isLastCardForAccount(String accountId) {
    return cardService.getAccountCards(accountId)
        .hasElement();
}

public Mono<List<Card>> getAccountCards(final String accountId) {
    return cardCrudRepository.getCardsByAccountId(accountId)
        .collectList();
}
```

The `collectList()` will emit an empty `List` if there is no card. I'd use `exists` query instead:

```java
public Mono<Boolean> isLastCardForAccount(final String accountId) {
    return cardCrudRepository.existsByAccountId(accountId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try this by updating the code accordingly! Will be reporting back here at some point!